# Insert a value from a select query

Tags: c#, mysql, database

```
        string ProductType = comboBoxProductType.Text;
        string ProductID = "Select ProductID from Productinformation where Name = '" + ProductType + "'";
        string query = "Insert into CustStoreProd (ProductID) VALUES (?ProductID)";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, mySQLconnection);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?ProductID", "ProductID");
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I want to insert the value from a Selection query "ProductID", I test that string `ProductID` works, and if I just insert a `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?ProductID", "1");`, it works too, but when I put `productID` into the `parameters.addwithvalue`, it doesn't work. It is just one of the function for the whole project so I create the mysql database connection outside.

Comment: You _could_ just use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`.  But you should parameterize your `WHERE` clause to avoid SQL injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you running the query ProductID. You aren't running the query ProductID to get ProductId and use it in the subsequent query.

First run ProductID query to get the product id from your table and then use the product id in the insert query. See sample code below.

```
string ProductType = comboBoxProductType.Text;
        string ProductID = "Select ProductID from Productinformation where Name = '" + ProductType + "'";
        string query = "Insert into CustStoreProd (ProductID) VALUES (?ProductID)";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(ProductID, mySQLconnection);
int pid = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()); //assuming product id is integer
        cmd.CommandText = query;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?ProductID", pid);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

modify below line from

`cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?ProductID", "ProductID");`

to

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?ProductID", ProductID);  //Remove "" around productID
```

Comment: I tried that but still doenst work. I try to change it to ("?ProductID", ProductType);, and if for example the producttype's value is 1, it works fine, but when I change back to productID which is the selection query, it does not work

Comment: Have you debugged? what is the value you are receiving for ProductID

Comment: @StevenHuang did you try replacing `?` with `@` ??

Comment: @SaqibMustafaAbbasi the value I got from ProductID is 1

Comment: @StevenHuang try executing your select query first. you just declared your query string. first fetch that product id then add it with parameter and see what happens.

Comment: @AsifRahaman, do you means I just run the string fst to get the value then use the value for the parameter, and do the two things same time?

Comment: @StevenHuang first part is correct. try getting the value of `ProductID` from db first then add it to `@ProductID` parameter. then execute your insert query.

Comment: @AsifRahaman I test the string ProductID, I can get the value from db.. or is there anything I missunderstand?

Comment: @StevenHuang some1 just answered what i was telling you about. check theshooter's answer.

Comment: @StevenHuang welcome :) You can only accept 1 answer as berst answer but upvote others to appreciate :)

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
string ProductType = comboBoxProductType.Text;
        string ProductID = "Select ProductID from Productinformation where Name = '" + ProductType + "'";
        string query = "Insert into CustStoreProd (ProductID) VALUES (@ProductID)";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, mySQLconnection);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductID", "ProductID");
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

change the value of ? to @ hope it helps.
or maybe your ProductID is an auto incremental primary key, cant be done on it.

Comment: is your productid is a primary key or not?